# Binding a Sequence of Tabularize Commands to One :Command

Tags: plugin-tabular

Is there a way to bind the sequence of commands

```
:Tabularize /\/\/
:Tabularize /;
```

in that order to the command `:Command`?

**EDIT:** I attempted the solution and it failed:

```
function! LineUp()
  normal :cabbrev Command Tabularize/\/\/<CR>:Tabularize /;<CR>
endfunction

command! -nargs=0 -complete=buffer -range LineUp call LineUp()
```

The problem is that I can't get it to act on the visual selection.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, try:

```
:cabbrev Command Tabularize/\/\/<CR>:Tabularize /;<CR>
```

Comment: I attempted to use this in a solution above but ran into a problem. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This also doesn't seem to work when ran without any selection on the whole file. Perhaps the <CR>'s aren't being registered as proper returns?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
function! CombinedTabularize() range
    execute a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . 'Tabularize /\/\/'
    execute a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . 'Tabularize /;'
endfunction

command! -range CT <line1>,<line2>call CombinedTabularize()
```

The function `CombinedTabularize()` takes a range thanks to the `range` option. When using this option the lines in the range are available with `a:firstline` and `a:lastline`.

The command `CT` also takes a range and pass the selected lines to the function with `<line1>` and `<line2>`.

The `execute` commands are used to concatenate the lines of the range and the `Tabularize` calls.

---

About the code you tried to use here are the different problems:

- Your command uses the `range` option but doesn't pass the lines to the function.
- Your function doesn't use the range neither
- Your function execute `normal :cabbrev` which creates a new command line abbreviation but doesn't execute it

---

You might be interested in the following help topics:

- `:h func-range`
- `:h command-range`